# How do I optimize a simple multivariate function in economics

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, economics

I apologize if this is simple but I have looked for over an hour and nothing has worked. I am attempting to use python to find the optimal level of `L` (Labor) and the output (Profit) given the objective function `5(12*L*K - 0.1*L^2*K) - 5*L - 5*K` when `K` is fixed at 10.

I have tried to use the following code from other answers to similar questions (using the '-' to maximize).

```
def micro(L):
   return 5(12*L*10 - 0.1*L**2*10) - 5*L - 5*10
results = minimize(-micro, 0)
```

I'm still new to python so I could just be completely off base. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And what happens when you do this?  By the way, `5(12...)` is not how you do multiplication in Python.  You need `5 * (12...)`.

Comment: This is a quadratic function `-5*L**2 + 595*L - 50`. Its maximum is attained for `L=59.5` (just calculate the derivative and set it to 0).

Comment: I have to do it in python though

Comment: You have three answer in python, would you mind review them?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.optimize.fmin` can do this:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import fmin
>>> def fn(x):
...     return -(-5*x*x+595*x-10)
... 
>>> fmin(fn,0)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -17651.250000
         Iterations: 37
         Function evaluations: 74
[59.5]
>>>
```

Comment: The answer was + for me. The index is fine. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

By using `np.arange` we create a NumPy array from 0 to 100 each time increasing by 0.1 then we plug it into the profit equation and we use `np.argmax` to return the index of the biggest profit witch will get us how much labor you have to do for it.

```py
import numpy as np
def find_optimal_L():
    L = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
    profit = 5*(12*L*10 - 0.1*L**2*10) - 5*L - 5*10
    return L[np.argmax(profit)], np.max(profit)

L,profit = find_optimal_L()
print(L,profit)
```

Comment: Except that the correct answer is not between 0 and 100.

Comment: You can change those numbers

Comment: @TimRoberts the best answer for this would probably be gradient descent or stochastic gradient descent

Comment: I typed the formula wrong -- the answer IS between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

This is other option:

```
my_results = []

def micro(L):
    result = 5*(12*L*10 - 0.1*L**2*10) - 5*L - 5*10
    my_results.append(result)
    return np.amax(my_results)
```

You can change the range here:

```
L = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
micro(L)
17651.232263294325 # Output
```

If you want to minimise, just change the `return`:

```
return np.amin(my_results) # -109550.0 Output
```